# Email validation tag input using jquery (using tag not normal input)

Tags: jquery, laravel, validation

```
$('#addLenderForm').validate({ // initialize the plugin
        errorClass: 'errors',
        rules: {
            email : email,
        }
```

Tag input email validation not working in jquery ,any other options for that validation.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use native js

```
function validateEmail(email) {
    var re = /^(([^<>()\[\]\\.,;:\s@"]+(\.[^<>()\[\]\\.,;:\s@"]+)*)|(".+"))@((\[[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\])|(([a-zA-Z\-0-9]+\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,}))$/;
    return re.test(String(email).toLowerCase());
}
```

Comment: Actually my problem ,is input tag validation ,not normal input validation